# XPC Service NSCocoaError domain

Tags: xcode, swift, macos

I've written an Application that uses XPC Service to communicate with its helper. The application launches and works as expected within Xcode.

However, the following error appears when I try to run the application outside of Xcode after I `Archive` it.

```
HideMyMac[27183:936477] XPCService error: Error
Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service named 
io.jabbari.HideMyMac.HideMyMac-XPCService" UserInfo=
{NSDebugDescription=connection to service named  
io.jabbari.HideMyMac.HideMyMac-XPCService}
```

Here is [the source](https://github.com/joubin/HideMyMac) of this application on Github. I normally would provide source with my code, however, the xml style plists would clutter the page and take away from the post.

Here what I have attempted:

Step 1: Updated - Main App Target -> Capabilities Tab

- Turned on 'App Sandbox'
- Turned on 'App Groups'
- Added an app group - 'XYZ'

Step 2: Updated - Helper Target -> Capabilities Tab

- Turned on 'App Sandbox'
- Enabled 'Outgoing Connections (Client)'
- Turned on 'App Groups'
- Added an app group - 'XYZ'

What am I missing anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably not a good question for StackOverflow, because it's a very project-specific configuration issue.

The actual problem you're running into is that the XPCService crashes immediately:

```
HideMyMac[5999]: XPCService error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service named io.jabbari.HideMyMac-XPCService" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service named io.jabbari.HideMyMac-XPCService}
ReportCrash[5995]: Saved crash report for HideMyMac-XPCService[6000] version ??? to …
```

this is because the SMJobKit framework cannot be found by the dynamic loader at the expected place:

```
Dyld Error Message:
Library not loaded: @rpath/SMJobKit.framework/Versions/A/SMJobKit
Referenced from: /Users/USER/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-02-24/HideMyMac 24.02.16, 16.32.xcarchive/Products/Applications/HideMyMac.app/Contents/XPCServices/HideMyMac-XPCService.xpc/Contents/MacOS/HideMyMac-XPCService
Reason: image not found
```

So, you should check the copy files / embed framework phases in Xcode's build phases tab.

Comment: Hey, how did you get the Crash report. I don't get that error on mine.

Comment: Here is what happens for me: https://www.dropbox.com/s/y571um6kmd6qm1t/XPCService.mov?dl=0

Comment: I've update the git repo to fix the error you got. Its because I didn't push the pod file update which added the framework to main project